# How android permission system works internally after reading manifest

Tags: android, android-permissions, signing

How Android tracks permissions granted to application after reading from manifest file? Are application permission tracked based on applicationId/package name/signing key/some other way?

If it stores permissions on some storage then how android will retrieve the permissions array/data to match. What will it use? Something like SHA, Apllication ID or Package name?

> Note : Marshmallow 6.0 is the Target Environment

Comment: It must be related to app's manifest file. OS will read AndroidManifest.xml file at the time of installation.

Comment: @OnkarNene please review question again.... I hope now question is clear....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Please take a look at following links -**

1) http://trendblog.net/android-app-permissions/

2) https://www.se.jku.at/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/2012.permission-tracking.pdf

> If Signature is specified, access is granted if a requesting
>   application is signed with the same certificate as the application
>   that declared the permission. The level SignatureOrSystem grants
>   access to applications that are in the Android system image or that
>   are signed with the same certificates as those in the system image.

So here `Signing Certificate` is the key ingredient which helps android system identify `permitted applications` for a specific Permission.

It may be helpful for you!

Answer (score 0):

The `android os`  will read the Manifest file of the Application.

Comment: Ok, agree....But I wants to know how it manages permissions after declaration in Manifest....I am talking about Android 6.0.

Comment: Android 6.0 follow the same approach but permission will given run time. if user deny the access simple the android will disable that permission for particular app.

Comment: So what i am asking how will android come to know that this permission is denied by user... where it stores the permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

Applications use a lot of permissions like using internet, accessing your phone book, accessing SD card, etc. Android shows what permissions an application needs before each install of the applications. User knows what permissions the application is using just before the application installation.

And Android knows this by going through the Androidmenifest file named *Androidmenifest.xml*. This file is contained in root directory of every Android applications. All of the permissions are controlled in there.

Structure of Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission />
<permission />
<permission-tree />
<permission-group />
<instrumentation />
<uses-sdk />
<uses-configuration />  
<uses-feature />  
<supports-screens />  
<compatible-screens />  
<supports-gl-texture />  

<application>

    <activity>
        <intent-filter>
            <action />
            <category />
            <data />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data />
    </activity>

    <activity-alias>
        <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
        <meta-data />
    </activity-alias>

    <service>
        <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
        <meta-data/>
    </service>

    <receiver>
        <intent-filter> . . . </intent-filter>
        <meta-data />
    </receiver>

    <provider>
        <grant-uri-permission />
        <meta-data />
        <path-permission />
    </provider>

    <uses-library />

</application>
```

Each permission is identified by a unique label and the label indicates tha action that is restricted. Some examples of permission defined by Android:

```
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA
android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER
android.permission.DEVICE_POWER
```

If an application needs permissions like the ones mentioned above, it must declare that with a `<used-permission>` element in the menifest file as shown below.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score -1):

In every android application, there is a file called AndroidManifest.xml which defines app's permission using tag called uses-permission. For example

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

which define permission for Internet usage.